# Range.insertText throws exception if entire contents of Word document are selected

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm working on an Word add-in that involves replacing the text selected by the user. For some reason it throws an exception if the user has selected the entire contents of the document.

The following will reproduce the problem for me:

`function convertSelectionToVariable() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        range.insertText('<<test>>', Word.InsertLocation.replace);
        return context.sync();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}`

If I create a .docx with the contents "ABC" and select just a subset of those characters, then this works fine and replaces the selection as expected. If I select the entire contents of the document, either by using the mouse or hitting ctrl-a, then I get an exception thrown while calling context.sync().

The exception message is "GeneralException", the name is "OfficeExtension.Error" and the stack trace is 

`GeneralException: GeneralException
   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:150094)
   at yi (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:163912)
   at st (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:163999)
   at d (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:163819)
   at c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:162405)`

Any suggestions/ideas on what's going wrong? I can't see anything in the docs for Range.insertText() which suggests it's invalid to call on a range including the entire document.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this using the latest version of Word 2016. Can you provide the full version number of Word that you are seeing this on?